# Send locale.storage email and new email axios post request

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, request

I am trying to change the email of the current logged in user.

Basically I have a field where I enter my "new" Email (component code):

```
 const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
.........
                        
 <input type="email" placeholder={user.email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
```

**my axios post request in the component** :

```
const changeEmail = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.post("/auth/change/", {
                    email: email
                }, {
                    headers: {
                        token:
                            "Bearer "+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).accessToken,
                    },
                }).then(r => console.log(r)).catch(err => console.log(err))
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
```

my current **server/routes/auth.js** :

```
router.post("/change", verify , async (req, res) => {
    if(req.body.email === '' || !(req.body.email.match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/g))){
        res.status(400).json("Email not valid")
    }
    try {
        User.findOne({
            where: {
                email: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).email
            },
        }).then((user) => {
            if(user === null) {
                console.log("email not in db")
                res.status(403).json("Email not valid")
            } else {
;               user.update({
                email : req.body.email
                })
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

My idea was to search for the locale.storage email in the db and if it was found update the user with the email that was set in the useState. But obviously locale storage is not useable in the api. Is there anyway to send the old and the new email to the post request in the api?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the email of the user from the localStorage in client side code like you have get the token.

```
const changeEmail = async () => {
 try {
    const res = await axios
    .post(
        "/auth/change/",
        {
        email: email,
        old_email: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).email
        },
        {
        headers: {
            token:
            "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).accessToken,
        },
        }
    )
    .then((r) => console.log(r))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
 }
};
```

and change the api handler to these(here we are trying to get the user from the old email and if found update the user email)

```
   router.post("/change", verify, async (req, res) => {
    if (
        req.body.email === "" ||
        !req.body.email.match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/g)
    ) {
        res.status(400).json("Email not valid");
    }
    try {
        User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.old_email,
        },
        }).then((user) => {
        if (user === null) {
            console.log("email not in db");
            res.status(403).json("Email not valid");
        } else {
            user.update({
            email: req.body.email,
            });
        }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });
```

don't forget to update the localStorage after updating the user email otherwise it will be in inconsistent stage.

Comment: How do I access the old_email in the server/api/routes/auth.js /change route code?

Comment: i have updated the answer. can you please check